# Linux disable/hide mtdblock devices from lsblk

Tags: debian, kernel, udev

I am running Debian on QNAP ts-119P+. It is running well, but I am experiencing
something a little bit annoying. When I use *lsblk*, there is obviously *sda*, but also flash memory chips (*mtdblockX*), that contain firmware and I will never need to access them in the system. Is there some way to hide them? I tried to hide them using udev rules, but with no luck. I am trying to disable them in kernel or somehow disable them from showing up in *lsblk*.

Comment: Udev is the right tool for this. What rules did you try?

Comment: @Gilles I tried ATTR{authorised}=0

Comment: @M.H. o hell no. `lsblk -t scsi` or something like that. do `lsblk --help` to find the exact options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide certain devices from being listed by `lsblk` with its `-e` (or `--exclude`) option as `lsblk -e <major number>`.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant kernel options are set in the `menuconfig` menu under "Device Drivers" -> "Memory Technology Devices (MTD)", so you can deselect the ones relevant to your case there.

Note that I see no benefit to hiding hardware components that may become useful one day.  It will also force you to build a customized kernel, which is never an easy task and remains fairly difficult for the first 20-30 times you change hardware components or kernel versions.

Comment: Is that a X solution? Because I am not running X on that machine. Also, * -bash: command menuconfig not found*

Comment: My answer was aimed at the person who asks `i am trying to disable them in kernel` since I expect that person to know what it implies to do it.  Building the kernel depends on many factors including the Linux distribution you're on and the hardware components.  It is accessible to most persevering people but requires a **lot** of reading the internal help and online documents to see what you should or shouldn't enable in your case.

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect that.  Finally note that you would have to disable automatic kernel updates (which could have side-effects because of package requirements and conflicts) and deal with them yourself to stay up to date.

Comment: @M.H. This answer proposes to compile a kernel with support for those devices disabled. This is not a good solution for reasons explain in that same answer. If you don't want those devices to appear because you fear accidentally accessing them, udev is the right way to suppress them.